# Android studio - dependent module not updating during build

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

Ok, so I have a project that I imported into Android Studio via a Maven POM file.

I have my application module which is dependent on other modules. When I alter a "sub module" and debug the application the module changes are not reflected.

What happens is I can step through the code alright, but the lines make no sense and it jumps out before the end of the code block is reached.

How can I have the code changes reflected in build and debug please?

Thanks

Comment: Restart Android Studio and/or reimport the project. What you experience is most likely a bug as long as you didn't mess with the default settings of the IDE when it comes to building. Taking a look at the build.gradle might also yield some results.

Comment: Thank you. This is a Maven project though.

Comment: It worked? And Android Studio only supports gradle projects. If you open a maven project it will be converted into a gradle project - or at least it should be. I never tried it, if you can work with maven projects natively in Android Studio than that seems to be a remnant from IntellIJ...

Comment: No, it didn't work. Are you sure that is the case with Maven?

Comment: No I am not, but you are the one who has opened the maven project. Just look at the project explorer. You shouldn't have a problem telling a gradle project apart from a maven project.

Comment: Oh, well it is definitely a Maven project.

Comment: And I assume you are sure that the there is nothing wrong with the pom files themselves? Did you test it somewhere else? I would test and see if it is working in IntelliJ.